# Convert Big Endian ELF executable into Little Endian endianness?

Tags: arm, elf, endianness

Is it possible to change the ELF endianness without impairing the code functionality, and the file format?

My goal is to run a Big Endian ARM executable on a Little Endian machine.

If it's not just swapping the bytes (due to headers and more I guess), what are the needed steps?

Comment: too vague, there are two arm big endian modes, it is possible assuming you have the right one for the core you are on and more importantly the chip/peripherals.  You could possibly switch the endian mode before loading and running this binary, but it also depends on your environment is this bare metal or on an operating system.  Bare metal there is a very slim chance, otherwise not likely.

Comment: be-32 the old way 32 bit things were not swapped, bytes and halfwords were.  So you would have to know which parts (on a word by word basis) of the binary is accessed as words and swap everything else.  be-8 the byte accesses dont change but word and halfword DATA accesses do, instructions dont, so you would have to isolate the bytes in the binary accessed as data words or halfwords and swap those.  short answer, swapping aint gonna work. have to switch the processor to the right mode assuming you are on a chip the binary would work on(perhipherals, etc)

Answer (score 2):

No. The endianness is not just in the file format but the ABI used within the code, both in form of machine instructions and data structures.

ARM BE/LE would be the same differences between x86 and ARM at that point, and can't "translated".

Comment: The code itself may use the endianess (e.g. read the first byte of a 4-byte int and assume it's the low byte). You will break pretty much all programs even if you translate the instructions properly.

Comment: Indeed. Similarly since ELF does not encode the semantics of the data structures that you access, it's impossible for a translation software to tell which parts of a structure you're accessing, and the order of the fields in the structure may be endianness-defined.